# Project Euler #119 Make Faster

Tags: java, performance

Trying to solve Project Euler problem 119:

> The number 512 is interesting because it is equal to the sum of its digits raised to some power: 5 + 1 + 2 = 8, and 8^3 = 512. Another example of a number with this property is 614656 = 28^4.
>
> We shall define an to be the nth term of this sequence and insist that a number must contain at least two digits to have a sum.
>
> You are given that a2 = 512 and a10 = 614656.
>
> Find a30.

**Question:** Is there a more efficient way to find the answer than just checking every number until a30 is found?

---

**My Code**

```
    int currentNum = 0;
    long value = 0;
    for (long a = 11; currentNum != 30; a++){ //maybe a++ is inefficient
        int test = Util.sumDigits(a);
        if (isPower(a, test)) {
            currentNum++;
            value = a;
            System.out.println(value + ":" + currentNum);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(value);
```

isPower checks if a is a power of test. Util.sumDigits:

```
    public static int sumDigits(long n){
        int sum = 0;
        String s = "" + n;
        while (!s.equals("")){
            sum += Integer.parseInt("" + s.charAt(0));
            s = s.substring(1);
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

program has been running for about 30 minutes (might be overflow on the long). Output (so far):

81:1

512:2

2401:3

4913:4

5832:5

17576:6

19683:7

234256:8

390625:9

614656:10

1679616:11

17210368:12

34012224:13

52521875:14

60466176:15

205962976:16

612220032:17

Comment: The substring part must be a killer...

Comment: There's probably a more efficient algorithm, but all that int/string conversion is likely expensive.  You can pull apart a number apart with some likely faster math.  Here % is the mod operator.  `512 % 10 = 2;  512 - 2 = 510;  510 % 100 / 10 = 1;  510 - 10 = 500;  500 % 1000 / 100 = 5;  500 - 500 = 0`

Comment: @assylias Util.sumDigits runs very fast alone, I think it might be the iteration in the for loop of the main body.

Comment: @Schwern I don't think Util.sumDigits is the problem. Does it really add that much time?

Comment: @gangqinlaohu Only way to know is to profile it.  Everything else is just guessing.  From your guess that `a++` might be the problem you really need to get some data.  String operations are generally more expensive than math.  The real improvement is going to be in the algorithm, lowering the number of iterations necessary, not the cost of individual operations.

Comment: `maybe ++a is inefficient` -- that really sounds like a joke.

Comment: Project Euler solutions should complete well within a minute. You have implemented the naive solution it seems, now look for a smarter one. No java tweaks will help. Rethink the math first, then the code.

Comment: @gangqinlaohu Measure the performance of the individual methods and operations in your code to figure out what is slow. This is called "profiling" and its done with a "profiler".  I'm not a Java programmer, so I can't recommend one. :-/  But ErikEkman is right, your performance woes are more about math than code.

Comment: As you are iterating the sum increases by one each time except multiples of ten.

Comment: An even number raised to any power is even. Ditto for odds. So if your digit sum is even and your number is odd (and vice versa) go no further. There are probably further cheap checks you could do.

Comment: Think I will us JasonD's solution (I hoped I wouldn't have to)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution is a 15 digit number. Good luck optimising the summing enough to make that run fast enough to check every single number.

Turn the problem on its head. The sum of digits is a relatively low number (maximum of 9 x number of digits in the number), and the powers will also be relatively low (it doesn't take a large power to raise even a small number to be 15 digits).

So loop over the sums and powers, calculate the total (you can keep a running total in the inner loop with a multiply, not even a power calc needed) and then sum the digits of that to see if it matches your loop variable.

The numbers won't be in order, so calculate more than you need and sort the results.

Should run in about a second.

Answer (score 5):

About that digit sum... here some hard facts:

```
 0% Scenario{vm=java, trial=0, benchmark=NaiveDigitSum} 542.90 ns; σ=11.00 ns @ 10 trials
50% Scenario{vm=java, trial=0, benchmark=BetterDigitSum} 42.13 ns; σ=1.42 ns @ 10 trials

     benchmark    ns linear runtime
 NaiveDigitSum 542.9 ==============================
BetterDigitSum  42.1 ==
```

Test code:

```
import com.google.caliper.Runner;
import com.google.caliper.SimpleBenchmark;

public class Performance extends SimpleBenchmark {
  public void timeNaiveDigitSum(int reps) {
    for (int r = 0; r < reps; r++) sumDigits(r + 1_000_000);
  }
  public void timeBetterDigitSum(int reps) {
    for (int r = 0; r < reps; r++) sumDigitsBetter(r + 1_000_000);
  }
  public static int sumDigits(long n){
    int sum = 0;
    String s = "" + n;
    while (!s.equals("")){
        sum += Integer.parseInt("" + s.charAt(0));
        s = s.substring(1);
    }
    return sum;
  }
  static int sumDigitsBetter(long n) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (; n != 0; sum += n % 10, n /= 10);
    return sum;
  }
  public static void main(String... args) {
    Runner.main(Performance.class, args);
  }
}
```

(spoiler solution removed, available through edit history)